# Non linear to linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, change-of-variable

Is there exist a non linear differential equation
$$
y'(t) = f(t,y(t))
$$
such that a change of variable $z=\varphi(t,y)$ leads to a linear differential equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can obtain such a nonlinear equation if you apply a nonlinear  change of variable to a linear equation.

Consider, for example, the equation
$$
\dot z =z,\quad z\in\mathbb R
$$
and the transformation
$$
y=\arctan z,\quad y\in \left(-\frac{\pi}2;\frac{\pi}2\right).
$$
Using the chain rule we can obtain
$$
\dot y= \frac{\dot z}{1+z^2}=\frac{z}{1+z^2}=\tan y\cos^2 y=\sin y\cos y
$$
The resulting nonlinear equation 
$$
\dot y=\sin y\cos y,\quad y\in \left(-\frac{\pi}2;\frac{\pi}2\right)
$$ can be transformed back to the linear form using the  change of variable $z= \tan y$